# Bayesian A/B testing and error estimates

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance, ab-test

Someone from my work started using an AB calculator that they found online and asked my take on the approach which i assume is incorrect. The approach takes the conversion and visits for control and variant A, and estimates significance using the following procedure:

1. Calculate the mean of variant A as $\mu_{a}$=conversion_a/control_a;
2. Calculate probability "prob" as BETA.DIST($\mu_{a}$, $\alpha_{prior}$+conversion_control, $\beta_{prior}$+visits_control-conversion_control,cumulative=True)
3. Calculate "significance" as prob*prob

As far as I can see, this is a mix of Baysian, using a posterior to get a posterior of the control conversion (using the beta+binomial conjugate), then estimating the probability of the mean of variant A and trying to pass that as a p-value. 
My main issues are:

- a) I don't see why assume a beta-binomial for the control, then use a point estimate (the mean) to them derive a simple probability (instead of using a comparison of both posteriors).
- b) Even if a is correct, the p-value would be the probability, not the probability squared.

So, am I correct in my assessments of a) and b) or am I missing something here? The excel source is from here: https://growthhackers.com/articles/bayesian-a-b-test-calculator-in-excel